# Equivalent version of \xrightarrow{} for \subseteq

Tags: code

If I want to denote the function `$f:X\rightarrow Y$` I can also write `$X\xrightarrow{f}Y$` which is useful when i write compiosite of maps or some commutative diagrams.

Do we have something similar in case of subseteq code?

I want to say `$U\subseteq X$` is open.

I want to write some thing like `$U\xsubseteq{Open} X$` which says that `$U$` is open in `$X$`.

Is there any code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\overset`, maybe you need also some kerning.

*Edit:* I've corrected my answer as egreg suggested to me in his comments.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\newcommand{\xsubseteq}{\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\mspace{-3mu}\mathrm{Open}\mspace{-3mu}}{\subseteq}}

\begin{document}
\[ 
U\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Open}}{\subseteq}X
\]
If you like to improve the kerning, you can adjust the spaces manually, for example (kerning according to my taste):
\[
U\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\!\mathrm{Open}\mspace{-4mu}}{\subseteq}X
\]
Of course, you can use a new command (kerning according to egreg's suggestion):
\[
U\xsubseteq X
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{Open}` instead of that clumsy `_\text{Open}`?

Comment: @egreg : You can write that as an answer. I am not able to see the difference.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You'd see a difference if you use the code in a theorem.

Comment: @egreg Simply because I'm not expert :):):)! I'll edit my answer if you don't want to add your one.

Comment: I agree with egreg here, `\text` is very wrong in this context. A lot of people make this mistake, as a consequence the rest of us spend a lot of time telling people not to.

Comment: @CarLaTeX By the way, the kerning should go around “Open”, not around the whole construction. And you don't need the `stackrel` package; `\overset` is better.

Comment: I'd still prefer `\scriptscriptstyle\mspace{-3mu}\mathrm{Open}\mspace{-3mu}`, which is conceptually better; I don't understand the reason for different kerns at the sides of the text.

Comment: @egreg I've corrected the kerning instruction position. As for the different kerns, it's only because the `X` seems farthest than `U` to me...